# Matching IP address in tcl without matching dotted strings

Tags: regex, ip, tcl

I'm trying to find all the IP addresses in a file and replace it with this pattern "***" but I end up matching dotted strings which look like IP addresses and replace/mangle them as well. Is there way out here? Maybe use tcl built in functions in the ip package?

The code looks something like this:

```
proc hide_ip { in_file } \
{
    set input_file [open $in_file]
    set file_content [read $input_file]
    set changed false 


    set ip_tags [list {(((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|(0?\d?\d))\.((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|(0?\d?\d))\.((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|(0?\d?\d))\.((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|(0?\d?\d))(/((3[0-2])|([1-2]?\d)))?)} \
                      {(((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2})|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,4})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(:(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:)))(%.+)?(/((12[0-8])|(1[0-1]\d)|(0?\d?\d)))?)}]

foreach item $ip_tags {
        set substituted [regsub -all -line -- $item $file_content {***} file_content]
        set changed [expr {$changed || $substituted}]
    }

...
```

192.168.1.1 --> This should match

12.192.168.1.1.567 --> This should NOT match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\b` to mark the boundary of your regexp so that it will not match the ones inside `12.192.168.1.1.567`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match `192.168.1.1` but not `12.192.168.1.1.567`, you could use a negative lookahead to exclude the second match.